# No key collision when returning identical arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694308/2030321) to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44694024/2030321) when I made an observation about `key`'s when returned from an array.

I already know that keys must be unique among sibling components. This is stated in the official React documentation, [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings):

> Keys used within arrays should be unique among their siblings. However they don't need to be globally unique. **We can use the same keys when we produce two *different* arrays**.

---

However, in contrast to the bold text above, it seems like React is fine with same keys for ***identical*** arrays. How come the following snippet works and the keys don't collide?

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  renderArray = () => {
    return [
      <p key={0}>Foo</p>,
      <p key={1}>Bar</p>,
      <p key={2}>Baz</p>
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderArray()}
        {this.renderArray()}
        {this.renderArray()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Obviously, this doesn't work:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p key={0}>Foo</p>
        <p key={1}>Bar</p>
        <p key={2}>Baz</p>
        <p key={0}>Foo</p>
        <p key={1}>Bar</p>
        <p key={2}>Baz</p>
        <p key={0}>Foo</p>
        <p key={1}>Bar</p>
        <p key={2}>Baz</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

So my question is, why does the first snippet work but not the second? It seems like they should both yield the exact same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer lays in how the `createHierarchyRenderer` method/function works. Source [createHierarchyRenderer.js](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/facebook/react/file/src/test/createHierarchyRenderer.js.html)

It is `reducingRight` and appending Components by render to the conspect concating the result.

It creates `renderHierarchy` which is 2d array of components, so... Your `renderArray` invocations have different indexes in hierarchy which makes their hierarchies independant of eachother.

Second case is not working, because key's are pseudohierarchy to boost performance - you **can** do this without keying, but - it is **very** bad practice for bigger render queue. So, passing key - overwrites the dimension represented by `key`.

#### Bonus:

Why it works without passing keys? Which keys are the best? How to improve?!

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5c6a496d98b80d19d851c2ec3a56d760b7118a50/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/traverseStackChildren.js):

> ```
> /**
>  * Generate a key string that identifies a component within a set.
>  *
>  * @param {*} component A component that could contain a manual key.
>  * @param {number} index Index that is used if a manual key is not provided.
>  * @return {string}
>  */
> function getComponentKey(component, index) {
>   // Do some typechecking here since we call this blindly. We want to ensure
>   // that we don't block potential future ES APIs.
>   if (component && typeof component === 'object' && component.key != null) {
>     // Explicit key
>     return KeyEscapeUtils.escape(component.key);
>   }
>   // Implicit key determined by the index in the set
>   return index.toString(36);
> }
> ```

This method is called by `traverseStackChildrenImpl` method in the same file. If you will dig into these magic:

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
>   child = children[i];
>   nextName = nextNamePrefix + getComponentKey(child, i);
>   subtreeCount += traverseStackChildrenImpl(
>     child,
>     nextName,
>     callback,
>     traverseContext,
>   );
> }
> ```

You will get why it is working, and you will know why the keying works without keys, **and** where you suffer performance looses. It is nice to pass `key` but... React can automagically pass the index for us, `key` is designed to take the `id` of component creator object... For example:

```
users.map((v, i) => (<UserItem data={v} key={i} />)
```

Makes no difference than not passing the `key`, but it is considered a **bad practice**:

```
users.map((v, i) => (<UserItem data={v} />)
```

`key` magic is designed to take id of user to not rerender rest of users in case of appending array inside fe. `users = users.unshift(someuser)`.
The best available setup is:

```
users.map((v, i) => (<UserItem data={v} key={v.userId} />)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! The latter snippet had keys only to demonstrate the (visual) identicality between the two. The reason I used keys at all is because that's required in the first. Anyway, many thanks again. Will dig into this a bit more and accept later on.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for possitive feedback, this is my first such deep dive into react source. I gave this text to my seniors from company that I am working for - for control that I wrotten. Probably I will speak with them and edit it with their experience.

Comment: No problem! I dug some as well and found some info as well. I posted an update below.

Answer (score 4):

After considering the valuable input from the other answers posted here, I dug a bit deeper and re-created the two snippets in my own application, and then inspected the Component with the React Developer Tool.

I found the following:

---

**First snippet:**

In the first snippet where the `renderArray()` function is used, the `children` of the parent `<div>` *does not* have 9 `<p>` tags as children but rather 3 arrays, each containing 3 `<p>` tags.

This isn't so apparent at first, because the rendered output in the dev-tools (left-hand part), suggests 9 children, not 3.

[image]

Here I have expanded the first, fourth and seventh item, which are the items which I have given `key` as `0`.

---

**Second snippet:**

In the second snippet where all `<p>` tags are placed directly as children of the `<div>` we get a similar output (if we ignore items 4-9 not showing, due to key collision), but the dev-tools show that the `<div>` has the expected 9 children. Hence the collision.

[image]

As with the previous snippet, I have expanded the first and fourth item where the `key` is `0`. (forgot the seventh).

---

**DL;DR**

To summarize, when a React Component is given an array as `children`, the contents of that array do not get unpacked/destructed and given as children. Instead, the array remains as `children` and serves as a transparent container for its contents.

As such, there is no key collision because:

- The parent `<div>` has 3 arrays as immediate `children` - not the 9 `<p>` components.
- Each `<p>` component is "locked" within its parent array, because that's where it's defined. It obviously cannot suddenly move into one of the other arrays.
- Each `<p>` component has a `key` inside its parent array (0-2); the only place collisions would be possible.

Comment: so it was because of `2D array`, finally mystery solved :)

Answer (score 1):

React keys must be unique for each element inside an instance of a parent. In your case, you have 3 instances of `{this.renderArray()}`, each with its own inner id. So children inside each instance have unique keys, but they are not siblings with children form other instances.

See this example from the official documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings